# Level curves don't match after rotation of function

Tags: python, numpy

Consider the general 2D Gaussian function, centered at (0.5,0.5),

`A*exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)`

where the covariance matrix can be written in terms of the coefficients a,b, and c as

2a  & b 
b & 2c

Rotating by 45 degrees counterclockwise gives

(a-b+c) & (a-c)
(a-c) & (a+b+c)

However, given a=1.25, b=0 and c=10000, and using Python to integrate over the unit square,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a=1.25
b=0   
c=10000
d=(a-b+c)/2
e=a-c
f=(a+b+c)/2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x,y=np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,1,50),np.linspace(0,1,50))
z=3*np.exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)
w=3*np.exp(-d*(-0.5 + x)**2-e*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-f*(-0.5 + y)**2) #rotated by 45 degrees counterclockwise
cs=ax.contour(x,y,z,levels=[0.8],colors='k',linestyles='dashed');
cs=ax.contour(x,y,w,levels=[0.8],colors='k',linestyles='dashed');

from scipy import integrate
h = lambda y, x: 3*np.exp(-a*(-0.5 + x)**2-b*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-c*(-0.5 + y)**2)
g = lambda y, x: 3*np.exp(-d*(-0.5 + x)**2-e*(-0.5 + x)*(-0.5 + y)-f*(-0.5 + y)**2)
print(integrate.dblquad(h, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1))
print(integrate.dblquad(g, 0, 1, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 1))
```

And output:

```
(0.061757213121080706, 1.4742783672680448e-08)
(0.048117567144166894, 5.930455188853047e-12)
```

As well as (where the one with coefficients a,b,c is the horizontal one, and the level curves are for C=z(x,y)=w(x,y)=0.8):

[image: Rotated vs. Non-rotated]

Comment: Maybe your rotation is incorrectly calculated. It might rotate to 45 degrees, but it can also stretch the space, so the integral changes

Comment: True. The rotation matrix is sqrt(2)/2 [[1, -1], [1, 1]], where the first list is the first row, the second the second row, and I think it should be consistent with the rotation matrix given on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Maybe the grid for which the level curves are plotted with needs to change as well.

Comment: actually that makes sense, you don't integrate over unit circle, you integrate over rectangle [0;1]^2, so the rotation sort of "cuts off" the edges of the rectangle

Comment: How does this explain the non-matching level curves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I meant in the comment, the integral probably changes due to integration over rectangle like this[image]

You can see that integrating over black rectangle isn't the same as over rotated green

Comment: Yes, nice illustration. However, it's strange that the level curves don't match.